# isChecked in dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I created some checkboxed dynamically in runtime, now i want to know ehen one of them ckecked or not. how i can do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                    cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    ll2 = new LinearLayout(
                            PollActivity.this);
                    ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    ll2.addView(cb);

                    ll.addView(ll2);

                }
```

Comment: Give us some code. Need to see how it was created

Answer (score 1):

you will need to set [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)  for CheckBox to fire an event when checkbox clicked. Example :

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

      // do your code here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set(in loop) for each `CheckBox` set [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      if (isChecked) {
         // do some action
      }     
   }
});
```

Now you are able to handle events for each CheckBox.

Comment: it doesn't work, can you give me a complete example? i cant do this for 1 day, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just check cb.isChecked() which returns a boolean value.